# Validation on arabic characters

Tags: javascript, html, arabic

I want t validate on text html to make it accept only arabic characters.how can i make this using java script.

Comment: As the first step, you need to define what you regard as “arabic characters.”

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
function arabicOnly(e){
  var unicode=e.charCode? e.charCode : e.keyCode
  if (unicode!=8){ //if the key isn't the backspace key (which we should allow)
      if (( unicode<48 || unicode>57) && (unicode < 0x0600 || unicode > 0x06FF)) //if not a number or arabic
        return false //disable key press
  }
}
```

Taken from [here](http://www.javascriptkit.com/javatutors/javascriptkey3.shtml) and adapted with information from [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arabic_characters_in_Unicode)

Answer (score 1):

1. Because JavaScript lacks built-in classes matching some scripts, you'll need to consult [Unicode code charts](http://www.unicode.org/charts/) and select ranges you need. I'm not that pro at Arabic, so I guessed you'll need at least Arabic (600-6ff), Arabic Supplement (750-77f), and Arabic Extended-A (8a0-8ff).
2. Construct an [Regexp](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions) that matches a string consisting only of those characters: `/^[\u0600-\u06FF\u0750-\u077F\u08A0-\u08FF]$/`
3. Use it in your own validation function if you have one or use any of many JavaScript form validation libraries (just search for those words in any engine to quickly find one).

Additionally, if library you use allows negative checks, you can invert range to avoid scanning entire string and bail on first wrong character: `/[^\u0600-\u06FF\u0750-\u077F\u08A0-\u08FF]/`.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use regular expression. 
Read this: 
http://www.javascriptkit.com/javatutors/redev3.shtml